# How to read and write to general purpose input output using GO?

Tags: go, gpio

I'm unable to find any documentation on this. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: http://godoc.org/?q=gpio

Answer (score 0):

For example [davecheney](https://github.com/davecheney) has some stuff:

1. [gpio](http://godoc.org/github.com/davecheney/gpio)

> Package gpio provides a user space interface to GPIO pins.

1. [rpi](http://godoc.org/github.com/davecheney/gpio/rpi)

> Package rpi provides a GPIO implementation customised for the RPi.